# Fastest way to get sum of `n` independent geometric random variables

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I have big integer `n` and geometric distribution:

```
n = 1000000
distribution = scipy.stats.geom(0.53284, loc=-1)
```

I want to count sum of `n` independent random variables of this distribution. I can do it so:

```
distribution.rvs(size=n).sum()
```

But this takes long time. What is more faster way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sum of independent geometric random variables [has a negative binomial distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/548525/1140).

Therefore, use [scipy.stats.nbinom](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.nbinom.html):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 10**4
p = 0.53284
nsamples = 10**3
distribution = stats.geom(p, loc=-1)
x = distribution.rvs(size=(nsamples, n))
total = x.sum(axis=1)

distribution2 = stats.nbinom(n, p)
total2 = distribution2.rvs(nsamples)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)
ax[0].hist(total, normed=True)
ax[0].set_title('by summing geom')
ax[1].hist(total2, normed=True)
ax[1].set_title('by using nbinom')
plt.show()
```

### [image]

For the example above, using `nbinom` is about 448x faster:

```
In [64]: %timeit distribution = stats.geom(p, loc=-1); distribution.rvs(size=(nsamples, n)).sum(axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 397 ms per loop

In [65]: %timeit distribution2 = stats.nbinom(n, p); total2 = distribution2.rvs(nsamples)
1000 loops, best of 3: 885 µs per loop

In [66]: 397000/885
Out[66]: 448.5875706214689
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I think that `loc=-1` is unnecessary for `scipy.stats.nbinom`, because [with `loc=-1` it `rvs` can return `-1`](https://ideone.com/X2h97D), and sum of `scipy.stats.geom(p, loc=-1)` is always non-negative?